# Create Package Manager Console Command

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I don't know much about NuGet, I only used it a few times to download a few things into my Visual Studio projects. I need to make a command, that can be entered into the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio, that would then create a solution with a variable number of C# projects in it (the variable would be passed as an argument in the command). I've seen it done before, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Why not create an extension to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at how Entity Framework does it - http://entityframework.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for something a little more beginner-friendly.